# Kendo Grid doesn't show any data despite having data within DataSource

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, datasource, display

So, I'm trying to make a readyonly grid with kendo that shows data, but whatever I do, the data does not get shown.

[The grid looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkcEi.png)

And here's the code:

```
    $("#Materials")
        .kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: [],
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "ID",
                        fields: {
                            ID: { type: "number", editable: false },
                            Code: { type: "string", editable: false },
                            Name: { type: "string", editable: false },
                            ExtDeviceCode: { type: "string", editable: false , nullable: true },
                            BaseUomLOVString: { type: "string", editable: false }
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 20
            },
            filterable: {
                extra: true
            },
            pageable: true,
            columns: [
                { field: "Code", title:"Code"},
                { field: "Name", title: "Name"},
                { field: "ExtDeviceCode", title:"External device code"},
                { field: "BaseUomLOVString", title: "UnitsOfMeasure" }
            ],
            editable: false
        });
```

This makes an empty grid with no data, which I later on fill with an Ajax call. As you can see from above picture, the grid contains the data but does **not display** it. The data inside the dataSource [looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi00a.png) or as Json:

```
[{
    "ID": 21150,
    "Code": "3",
    "ExtDeviceCode": null,
    "Name": "Avio benzin",
    "BaseUomLOVString": "Kilogram"
}, {
    "ID": 21400,
    "Code": "5003",
    "ExtDeviceCode": null,
    "Name": "Bencin 95",
    "BaseUomLOVString": "Litre"
}]
```

**EDIT 1**:  I'm filling the data with an Ajax call like this:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '@SimpleUrlHelper.UrlObjectToRoot(Url)/FuelPointMaterialTankMask/LookupMaterials',
                data: {
                    //Send list of IDs
                    'materialIDs': materialList
                },
                type: "POST",
                success: function (response) {

                    var tmp = [];
                    if (typeof response !== "undefined" && 
                    response !== null) {
                        response.forEach(function(item) {
                            tmp.push(item);
                        });
                    }
                    grid = $("#Materials").data("kendoGrid");
                    originalMaterialDataSource = grid.dataSource;
                    originalMaterialDataSource.data(tmp);
                    originalMaterialDataSource._destroyed = [];
                    originalMaterialDataSource.pageSize(pageSize);
                    originalMaterialDataSource.page(1);
                    originalMaterialDataSource._total = tmp.length;
                    grid.pager.refresh();
                }
            });
```

Comment: How are you filling the grid after the ajax call?

Comment: Sorry for late response! Added the Ajax call code above to the "Edit" paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after days of trying to figure out what was wrong I finally found the answer.

Somewhere along the lines I had:

```
var grids = $('.k-grid');
for (var i = 0; i < grids.length; i++) {
        ....
grid.dataSource.filter().filters[0] = {
       logic: "or",
       filters: filters
}
        ....
```

So basically I was putting filters on all grids without excluding this one, which was just a bug from my part.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your data in your dataSource after your ajax call.

```
var dataArray = [{
    "ID": 21150,
    "Code": "3",
    "ExtDeviceCode": null,
    "Name": "Avio benzin",
    "BaseUomLOVString": "Kilogram"
}, {
    "ID": 21400,
    "Code": "5003",
    "ExtDeviceCode": null,
    "Name": "Bencin 95",
    "BaseUomLOVString": "Litre"
}];
```

Use `.data()` to set:

```
$("#Materials").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data(dataArray );
```

Comment: I did try to fill the data with your code as soon as the grid is created and the result is the same. The dataSource.data() has the data within but the $('#Materials').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.view() is always empty and nothing is displayed. Its like if the grid was collapsed.